# About the German sound of "R" as in "mehr"

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-sounds

As I already knew, "R" in German is pronounced as "R" in French, and "er" in "Bruder" is pronounced approximately as "Brude" without "R"...
but the "r" in "mehr" is not pronounced as "R" in French, why?

Comment: I do not think that it is.

Comment: Ich will määähhhaaa

Comment: For the record, if you need help pronouncing "mehr," listen to the Rammstein song by that name.  It's catchy and if you sing along you'll get lots of practice. :-)  http://www.metrolyrics.com/mehr-lyrics-rammstein.html

Answer (score 3):

Again I'm on my quest to add some IPA to this site:

How *Bruder* is pronounced was explained [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9784/5016), so I'm not going to repeat that.

Now for *mehr*. In [IPA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen) you would write:

> [ˈmeːɐ]

The difference is that in this case, we have a stressed *e* and not a *schwa* [ə] as in *Bruder*. [eː] is a vowel that is produced in the front part of the mouth, whereas [ə] is in the center. As you already know that the *r* is usually pronounced [ʁ], which is a uvular (back of the mouth) fricative, it is easy to see that the way from [eː] to [ʁ] is farther than from [ə] to [ʁ]. If something is very far away, you ususally end up somewhere in the middle. This is called assimilation. And [ɐ] just happens to be halfway from [eː] to [ʁ].

Another aspect that contributes is, that unlike French, in German there is not much emphasis on the last consonant. To compare with *la mère*:

> [ˈmɛʁ] or ['mɛʀ]

So the French tend to more clearly articulate the end consonants, at least if there is an *e* written at the end. The *e* is not pronounced, but it still makes the consonant better audible. Also, apparently [ʀ] is the predominant pronunciation of *r* in French, which is a trill and not merely a fricative, so it is even better audible, but otherwise very similar. If the *r* is between two vowels in German, the same happens, so for *die Meere* we get:

> [ˈmeːʁə]

I don't really know about people who roll their *r* (as for example in Bavaria), but according to Wikipedia and my own experience the [ʁ] variant is the one most widely used in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

If an -r is the final letter of a word, the it is usually pronounced similar to an short "a". *Mehr* is no exception to that.

> Mutt(e)a, Brud(e)a, Wint(e)a, meea, voa, Uua..

The proper IPA symbol is different.

Answer (score 0):

"Bruder" is really not spoken without the "r", except if you are talking some kind of slang. It may sound like "Bruda" when spoken in some regions, but this is just a local dialect.

Comment: I think you meant *dialect*, not *slang*.

Comment: Also: http://www.hueber.de/woerterbuch/online/?wb=&wbolang=de&sString=Bruder&modus=de-en&site=1&rl=true

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Slang in the sense of sociolect is quite correct here. This sociolectical feature is based on emigrant accent/dialect, but is also found in non-emigrant youth culture.