# Spricht man das 'r' in "Verlust"?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-sounds

Bei der Aussprache des Wortes "Verlust", spricht man das 'r'? Und auch wenn ja, tut man es immer, oder darf/will man es manchmal (zum Beispiel, wenn schnell gesprochen wird) auslassen?

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/german-english/Verlust mit Beispielen der Aussprache.

Comment: Das 'r'  in "Verlust" wird (im Standarddeutschen) [ausgesprochen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verlust) wie das 'r'  in "der", nämlich als [Tief-Schwa](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_offener_Zentralvokal).

Comment: @Roland: das sehe ich anders. Das r in der Mitte bei Verlust unterscheidet sich vom r am Ende. Auch anatomisch ergibt sich da eine andere Zungenbewegung. Ich denke das sollte man nicht vermengen. Auch wenn es lokale Unterschiede gibt, und ein bischen Akzent schadet nicht ...

Comment: Es gibt schon ein paar recht ähnliche Fragen [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6472/1696), [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6618/1696) und [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9411/1696).

Comment: @guidot Ich spreche kein English

Comment: @a_donda Die beiden Buchstaben "er"  werden in "Kinder" als /ɐ/ (Tief-Schwa) ausgesprochen, in "der" dagegen als Diphthong /eːɐ̯/ oder /ɛːɐ̯/. Für das "er" in "Verlust" ist nach meinem Eindruck /ɐ/ üblich; bei besonders sorgfältiger Aussprache ist aber auch ein Diphthong möglich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im Studium haben wir es so gelernt, dass man ein vokalisches R [ɐ] in der unbetonten Silbe -er- und damit auch Vorsilben wie ver-,her-, etc. spricht. Dieses deckt sich mit diversen Linguistik Seiten:

> Der [ɐ]-Laut ist die vokalische Aussprachevariante für das .
> Das  wird am Ende eines Wortes sowie in den Präfixen er-, ver- und zer-
> vokalisch ausgesprochen. Außerdem wird  in Verbindung mit  am
> Ende einer Silbe (-er, -ern, -ert u.a.) als [ɐ] gesprochen.

> Bei Wörtern, die auf -er enden und auch keinen weiteren Vokal besitzen, wie z.B. der oder in den Präfixen er-, ver- oder zer-, wird nur das  zu einem [ɐ]. Somit ist die Aussprache von der nicht [dɐ], sondern [deːɐ].

(https://fit-aussprache.com/de/archives/147)

Wenn das Wort schnell gesprochen wird, wird das R weiterhin vokal gesprochen, allerdings wird oft das -er zum a verformt. Ich denke, dass sich das vlt. so anhört, als würde das R nicht mehr ausgesprochen werden und es hört sich eher nach "Varlust" mit einem schwachen R als "Verlust" an, auch wenn es weiterhin betont ist.

Comment: Im Lied "Sonne" von Rammstein kann ich den Sänger das 'r' in "Verlust" überhaupt nicht artikulieren hören, aber vlt können Muttersprachler das doch hören

Answer (score -2):

Ich denke, normalerweise ist das "r" stumm. Mir fällt kein Wort beginnend mit "Ver" ein, dass ich mit einem klaren "R" ausspreche. Verliebt, Verdünnung, Versuchung, Verstand ... alles bei mir ohne klar artikuliertes "R".

Comment: Ich widerspreche... in meinem Sprachgebrauch haben alle Deine Beispielworte ein klar artikuliertes "R"... das hängt möglicherweise stark vom Dialekt ab...

Comment: Das „r“ kann vokalisch realisiert werden (ich benutze hier Wörter, die nicht aus meinem Fach sind, deshalb schreibe ich auch keine Antwort), aber das macht es nicht stumm.

Comment: @TorstenLink Auch im Standarddeutschen ist es nicht stumm.

Comment: Hört mal einem Mittelfranken zu, wenn er das Wort spricht - Da ist das "r" der wichtigste Buchstabe ;)